# How to trigger Angular-Strap modal with event other than click event?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Angular Strap V2's modal seems to have lost some functionality of V1, and I'm struggling to work out how to achieve what was fairly straightforward with V1 (using angular-strap's $modal service).

The documentation only shows an example where the modal is attached to a DOM element like a button and seems to be automatically wired to the click event. However I want to use other events eg SwipeLeft is a common convention for deleting something, but I'd like to pop up an "Are you sure?" modal prompt for this action.  Is this possible?

Is there any way to use the V2 modal with any event other than the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it looks like you can bind your own events, or use the default `click` event.

It should work if you add a `data-trigger='myEvent'` to your markup.

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L279